# grep to match whole number

Tags: jquery, json, grep

Can you help me fix my problem?

I need to only return the data below that has a 1 value. Currently it will return 1 and 10 in my example below.

If I search 10 I get just 10 back but if I search 1 I get 1 and 10.

```
var searchIn = [{"curAction":"10"},{"curAction":"1"},{"curAction":"5"}];
var searchTerm = "1";

var filtered_result = $.grep(searchIn, function(myobj, i) {
    return (myobj.curAction.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1);
});

storage = JSON.stringify(filtered_result); // Set the resulting JSON 
string as the echo string, input

alert(storage);
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vinny2010b/28h0gjct/12/)

Comment: Use `return myobj.curAction === searchTerm;` instead of the call to `indexOf` and comparison with -1.

Comment: OK, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
return myobj.curAction === searchTerm;
```

...instead of the call to `indexOf` and the comparison with -1.

That way you will only return `true` in the `$.grep` callback for exact matches.